Transfering sol from pda to a hardcoded account pubkey
Can i transfer money from a program owned PDA to a hardcoded pubkey without AccountInfo of the receiver ? Or do I NEED to pass it from the client?
let hardcoded_pubkey = Pubkey::from_str("----pubkey------").map_err(|_| ProgramError::InvalidArgument)?;
**pda_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= cost;
**hardcoded_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += cost;


This isn't possible, with Anchor. You need to pass in the required AccountInfo's to use them and can't do anything, except address validations if you pass in a public key address
To transfer sol
ctx.accounts.pda_account.sub_lamports(amount)?;
ctx.accounts.to.add_lamports(amount)?; 

ref: https://www.anchor-lang.com/release-notes/0.29.0#lamport-utilities
